# How to use a class without declaring object

Tags: vb.net, class, object

I'm trying to develop a class in VB .NET in order to manage a language globalization stored in a database and editable by the user.

What I need is to know what kind of class I need to declare in order to use it without declaring a new object. For example, the way My.Settings is used.

One of the goals is that in some project the developer imports the reference and after that access directly to a property. For example: My.CustomLanguage.GetWord("Hello") without declaring objects.

Is this possible? And if it's what is the best way to aproach it?

Thank you.

Comment: Alex means you should vote up if one answer is good and accept it if it solves your issue. Be a good citizen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare every property or method that you need to access as static, in VB, "Shared"

```
Shared Sub GetSomething()


MySharedClass.GetSomething()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a class with only static methods and fields

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a singleton class.

After declaring your class add a public static property having the same type as your class.
This will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

### First Make Class as

```
Public Class ClsTemplate
Public Shared Sub GridTemplate(ByVal DataGrid As DataGridView)
    DataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGrid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    DataGrid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = False
    DataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGrid.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    DataGrid.BackgroundColor = Color.White
    DataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
    DataGrid.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = Nothing
    DataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    DataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight = 20
    DataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =   DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing
    DataGrid.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    DataGrid.MultiSelect = False
    DataGrid.ReadOnly = True
    DataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = False
    DataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    DataGrid.StandardTab = True
End Sub
End Class
```

---

you can call this class direct by this code in your form

```
 ClsTemplate.GridTemplate(DataGridView1)
```